# How do I aggregate a dataframe and sum the values of a column by repeated rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I'm attempting to aggregate a dataframe to remove repeated rows, but I need to sum the value of a count column and use it as the new count for that row value. I have the following dataframe:

```
  count        freq  cdr3nt cdr3aa         v      d       j  VEnd  DStart   DEnd   JStart
   3154    0.036110 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
   2800    0.038394 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
   2608    0.033014 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
    412    0.004717 TGCGCCA  CASMG   TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1   9    15       19     20
    366    0.005015 TGCGCCA  CASMG   TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1   9    15       19     20
    310    0.004250 TGCAGTG  CSARD   TRBV20-1 TRBD1 TRBJ1-5  15    17       23     31
```

I need to get to this:

```
   count    freq    cdr3nt    cdr3aa   v       d     j     VEnd  DStart   DEnd   JStart
   8562    0.048822 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
    778    0.003332 TGCGCCA  CASMG   TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1   9    15       19     20
    310    0.004250 TGCAGTG  CSARD   TRBV20-1 TRBD1 TRBJ1-5  15    17       23     31
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
      count    freq    cdr3nt    cdr3aa   v       d     j     VEnd  DStart   DEnd   JStart
        3    0.601110 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
        2    0.506717 TGCGCCA  CASMG   TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1   9    15       19     20
        1    0.004250 TGCAGTG  CSARD   TRBV20-1 TRBD1 TRBJ1-5  15    17       23     31
```

Here's piece of the code that's not working right:

```
  agg_df <- within(aggregate(count ~ cdr3nt + cdr3aa + v + d + j + VEnd + DStart + 
             DEnd +   JStart, data = final_df, 
                FUN = length), freq <- count/sum(count))


  agg_df1 <-select(agg_df, count, freq, cdr3nt, cdr3aa, v, d, j, VEnd, DStart, DEnd, JStart)
```

Instead of adding the "count" value of the corresponding repeated rows, so I can recalculate the frequency, it's basically counting the number of times the particular row is repeated.  Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please provide code to make a reproducible example, check out the `dput()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `FUN = length` causes the output value of `count` to be the number of occurrences for each of the by groups. Instead, use `FUN = sum` to calculate the sum of the input `count` column.

```
textFile <- "  count        freq  cdr3nt cdr3aa         v      d       j  VEnd  DStart   DEnd   JStart
   3154    0.036110 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
   2800    0.038394 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
   2608    0.033014 TGTGCCA  CASSE   TRBV6-1  TRBD1 TRBJ2-6  13    18       22     24
    412    0.004717 TGCGCCA  CASMG   TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1   9    15       19     20
    366    0.005015 TGCGCCA  CASMG   TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1   9    15       19     20
    310    0.004250 TGCAGTG  CSARD   TRBV20-1 TRBD1 TRBJ1-5  15    17       23     31"

final_df <- read.table(text = textFile,
                   header = TRUE)

# original code had FUN = length, which returned the number of rows per
# combination of by groups 
agg_df <- within(aggregate(count ~ cdr3nt + cdr3aa + v + d + j + VEnd + DStart + 
          DEnd +   JStart, data = final_df, FUN = sum), freq <- count/sum(count))
agg_df
```

...and the output:

```
> agg_df
   cdr3nt cdr3aa        v     d       j VEnd DStart DEnd JStart count       freq
1 TGCGCCA  CASMG TRBV10-2 TRBD1 TRBJ1-1    9     15   19     20   778 0.08062176
2 TGTGCCA  CASSE  TRBV6-1 TRBD1 TRBJ2-6   13     18   22     24  8562 0.88725389
3 TGCAGTG  CSARD TRBV20-1 TRBD1 TRBJ1-5   15     17   23     31   310 0.03212435
>
```

We can confirm accuracy of the `freq` column as follows:

```
> # confirm accuracy 
> agg_df$count / sum(agg_df$count)
[1] 0.08062176 0.88725389 0.03212435
>
```

Comment: So the code was essentially ok, except for the FUN function.  Great catch.  Thanks.  I'd been racking my head trying to trace the problem.  It checks out on my original data set.  Thanks a million.

Comment: @Orion11 - you're welcome. Yes, the code was fine except for the `FUN=` argument.